# I have installed Ubuntu along Win10 in my laptop (Legacy) successfully, but there is no easy/convenient way to choose the OS I want to use

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I have recently bought an HP 15-BS540TU, which had pre-installed Windows 10 in it. The machine has BIOS legacy, NOT UEFI. I successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTE alongside the pre-installed Win10.

But now here's the problem (not problem per se, but yeah).

When I power on my laptop, it loads the Grub screen, which has 4 options. The first is simply `Ubuntu` and the last option is `Windows 10`. So *that's* the choice that I get. Now if I want to load into Windows 10, I enter it, but it takes a hell load of time to get it up and running, around 3-5 minutes, and it really seems a lot (considering the fact that before the installation of Ubuntu it took at most 30 seconds).

Is that the dual boot screen I should be expecting? And isn't/shouldn't there be a quicker way to load the OS's?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it is BIOS/MBR? Vendors are required by Microsoft to install Windows 10 in UEFI/gpt mode (as it boots quicker). And grub will not boot hibernated Windows, so if you turn on fast start on (hibernation) in Windows you cannot boot from grub. And if BIOS you then have to reinstall Windows boot loader to MBR to boot Windows. If UEFI you can still directly boot from UEFI menu.  Make sure you have made the Windows repair flash drive before any more changes. And a good backup.

Comment: My Ubuntu and Windows take about the same amount of time after they have been shut down. About 10 seconds.

Answer (score 7):

That dual boot screen you're getting is expected behaviour. Something similar happened to me when I dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu. Some research led me to the conclusion that when you're just running Windows, it doesn't shut down completely when you select the Shut Down option. Instead, it hibernates. This was first implemented in Windows 8.

I think what's happening is that Windows is getting completely shut down now, and hence it's taking longer to reboot. I found a link that may help you change a setting inside Windows which will make it hibernate, instead of completely shut down. Do remember though, that you won't be able to access the Windows partition when you're booted into Ubuntu.
https://www.howtogeek.com/262325/why-is-windows-hibernating-instead-of-fully-shutting-down/